# issue connecting with ssh

Tags: ssh

I am having issue where I can't SSH to my server. I was having a look at some logs on the server, finished and just closed the connection. As soon as I tried connecting again I got the message: ssh: connect to host SERVERIP port 22: Connection refused.

Here is the debug log:

```
XXXXX:~ XXXXXX$ ssh -vvvv XXXXX@serverip
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to SERVERIP [SERVERIP] port 22.
debug1: connect to address SERVERIP port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host SERVERIP port 22: Connection refused
```

I can see it refers to line 21 but nothing was changed in the config file, any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Connection refused` is a generic socket/service related error, it is typically shown when establishing a socket where the remote endpoint has no listener on the desired port.

In this case the remote server must not have the `ssh` daemon running, so does not have anything listening on port 22 (presumably), or a highly unlikely possibility is that the `ssh` daemon itself is having issues.

So make sure the `ssh` daemon is running (and functioning properly) on remote host you are trying to connect to.

Comment: yep that is also something i noticed when i was on server earlier, the status of ssh was "stop/waiting". this is vps so i dont have any other access than ssh to it. would restarting the server maybe solve it?

Comment: @StephanGriesel Don't they provide any console? If the `ssh` service is set to be started at system boot (and you have no other way to get in and start the daemon), then restarting would definitely work.